# How do I delete orphan entities using hibernate and JPA on a many-to-many relationship?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

I want to delete orphan entities using hibernate and JPA on a many-to-many relationship but all that I found was the attribute `org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN`, which works only for one-to-many relationships.

I want to know if I can delete the orphan ones on my many-to-many relationship.

Answer (score 15):

From the book "Pro JPA 2":

> Only relationships with single cardinality on the source side can
>   enable orphan removal, which is why the orphanRemoval option is
>   defined on the @OneToOne and @OneToMany relationship annotations, but
>   on neither of the @ManyToOne or @ManyToMany annotations.

It's a bummer, but there is no JPA automated orphan removal for ManyToMany.

Answer (score 7):

Actually, I did a test with the following entities:

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    @ManyToMany
    @Cascade(value = org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN)
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<Role>();

    //...
}

@Entity
public class Role {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
    private Set<Person> persons = new HashSet<Person>();

    //...
}
```

And with the following dataset:

```
<dataset>
    <PERSON id="1" firstname="john" lastname="doe"/>
    <PERSON id="2" firstname="clark" lastname="kent"/>
    <PERSON id="3" firstname="james" lastname="bond"/>
    <ROLE id="1" name="foo"/>
    <ROLE id="2" name="bar"/>
    <ROLE id="3" name="boo"/>
    <ROLE id="4" name="baz"/>
    <PERSON_ROLE persons_id="1" roles_id="1"/>
    <PERSON_ROLE persons_id="1" roles_id="2"/>
    <PERSON_ROLE persons_id="2" roles_id="2"/>
    <PERSON_ROLE persons_id="2" roles_id="3"/>
    <PERSON_ROLE persons_id="3" roles_id="1"/>
    <PERSON_ROLE persons_id="3" roles_id="4"/>
</dataset>
```

The following test method:

```
@Test
public void testCascadeDeleteOrphanOnDelete() {
    Person person = entityManager.find(Person.class, 1L);
    entityManager.remove(person);
    ReflectionAssert.assertPropertyLenientEquals("id", Arrays.asList(2, 3), findAllPersons());
    ReflectionAssert.assertPropertyLenientEquals("id", Arrays.asList(3, 4), findAllRoles());

}

private List<Person> findAllPersons() {
    return entityManager.createQuery("from Person").getResultList();
}

private List<Role> findAllRoles() {
    return entityManager.createQuery("from Role").getResultList();
}
```

Just passes. Below the produced output:

```
Hibernate: select personx0_.id as id17_0_, personx0_.firstName as firstName17_0_, personx0_.lastName as lastName17_0_ from Person personx0_ where personx0_.id=?
Hibernate: select roles0_.persons_id as persons1_1_, roles0_.roles_id as roles2_1_, rolex1_.id as id18_0_, rolex1_.name as name18_0_ from Person_Role roles0_ left outer join Role rolex1_ on roles0_.roles_id=rolex1_.id where roles0_.persons_id=?
Hibernate: delete from Person_Role where persons_id=?
Hibernate: delete from Role where id=?
Hibernate: delete from Role where id=?
Hibernate: delete from Person where id=?
Hibernate: select personx0_.id as id17_, personx0_.firstName as firstName17_, personx0_.lastName as lastName17_ from Person personx0_
Hibernate: select rolex0_.id as id18_, rolex0_.name as name18_ from Role rolex0_
```

Comment: Yes ! I´ve tested this too. It really deletes all the depedent roles (in this case) but I can´t do that. I need to delete only the orphan ones...

Thanks for you help !

Comment: @user368453: Indeed, it's like Hibernate cascaded the DELETE (and I understand now that this is not what you want). I wonder if Hibernate can do better.

Comment: Yes ! I wish it could... but It seems I´ll have to create a trigger on the database for doing that =/

Comment: This solution also relies on Hibernate and breaks JPA portability.

Comment: Please don't use this. it deletes related entities even if it not orphan

Answer (score 6):

So far there is no **orphanRemoval** attribute for the ManyToMany annotation. I have the same problem too. And the suggestion to implement it to on the database is no answer to the problem. The whole philosophy of JPA is *against* implementing logic on the database, but through the mappings.

Answer (score -28):

try this:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "yourObject")
```

Comment: like comment below says, there is no such attribute on the ManyToMany-annotation.